# How to redirect to another route?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For example, there is a button "Create" in my page, and it has ng-click attribute:

```
<button ng-click="create()">Create</button>
```

And in the `create()` function, I want to do something, then redirect to another route `#/show`, which is a client site route defined in angularjs:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.create = function() {
        // do something
        // how to redirect to `#/show`, another view and controller will be used
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $location) {
    $scope.create = function() {
        // do something
        $location.path('/show');
    }
}
```

[See `$location` API](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24location)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**$location**](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24location), the built in service to do that.